# How to pass an array in Wiremock query parameters

Tags: wiremock

It is couple days now, i'm stuck with Wiremock. I cannot figure out how to send an array parameters in GET method.
i want to send this `GET http://localhost/test?filter[]=full&token=any`.
so my json look like that

```
{
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "urlPath": "/test?filter[]=full",
        "queryParameters": {
             "token": {
                 "matches": "^[A-Za-z0-9-_=.]*$"
             }
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200
    }
}
```

but i got an error, here the error response

```
| Closest stub                                             | Request                                                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           |
GET                                                        | GET
/test?filter[]=full                                        | /test?filter[]=full&token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6Ikp<<<<< URL does not match
                                                           | XVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1MTYyMzkwMjJ9.tbDepxpstvGdW8TC3G8zg4B6rU
                                                           | YAOvfzdceoH48wgRQ
                                                           |
Query: token [matches] ^[A-Za-z0-9-_=.]*$                  | token:
                                                           | eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1MTYyMzkw
                                                           | MjJ9.tbDepxpstvGdW8TC3G8zg4B6rUYAOvfzdceoH48wgRQ
                                                           |
                                                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

so if anyone know how to send an array parameter with a `GET` method, i will appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're putting a query parameter in the URL path:

`"urlPath": "/test?filter[]=full"`

What you need to do is move `filter[]` into the query parameters block:

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPath": "/test",
    "queryParameters": {
      "token": {
        "matches": "^[A-Za-z0-9-_=.]*$"
      },
      "filter%5B%5D": {
        "equalTo": "full"
      }
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200
  }
}
```